# Switch two WPF Applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two WPF Applications, for example, one is `A_wpf` application, the others is `B_wpf` application.
There are one `Button` on each application. I want to `Button` in `A_wpf` application to Start up `B_wpf` application and show `B_wpf` with Maximized. I want to `Button` in `B_wpf` application to do the same thing as `A_wpf` Application do.

Could anyone give me any advices please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Process.Start(path_to_exe)`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

//...

Process.Start(path_to_exe);
```

Now if you want to avoid opening another instance if the target application is *already* running, you coud [use `Mutex` for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522874/401828).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But there is another problem: How `A_wpf` switch `B_wpf` like `Alt + Tab` do. `A_wpf` swith `B_wpf`, `B_wpf` must on top of the desktop.

Comment: In this case, I would go for inter-process communication between the applications. The only method I know is socket communication via localhost, but I'm not sure it's the best or even the only way.